# .png image and text fuzzy

Tags: png

I have a new email signature image and text that I have created in Canva pro. downloaded as a .png and attached it to the manage signatures section in outlook. Unfortunately the text is very blurry and I need to rectify this. Can you help at all. FYI - I don't have illustrator so a SVG file isn't possible - only jpg or png.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to export an SVGs from Canva Pro.  Do File > Download,  then choose SVG as the file type. To be honest though not sure all email clients will support SVGs, so maybe not a good idea. The image example you posted is too low resolution. Export it at a larger size (i.e. with larger pixel dimensions).

Comment: I'd try some `email signature generator` because they export html where text is text... and links are clickable. The only one I can kinda sorta recommend is https://www.hubspot.com/email-signature-generator when you start filling in your details it kinda just collapses everything you see in the preview so you can add just the details you want. I think I remember using it once...

Answer (score 2):

The image is too small.

Either export it at 800px width and live with the fact that it is slightly blurry and not selectable & clickable.

Or the better version; hire someone that codes this as html email signature.